# Length of find_elements_by_xpath is incorrect

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath

In the link below, I am trying to collect the total number of games in the 2023-24 Regular Season table.

https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/j/jokicni01/gamelog/2024

I have the variable for those elements set to total_games. My issue is when I do print(len(total_games), I am getting an output 113.

```
total_games = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//tbody/tr[@id and @data-row]')
print(len(total_games))
```

I have manually inspected the elements on the page and done a search for //tbody/tr[@id and @data-row] and even in the search results it shows only 66 entries (accurate as of Mar 19, 2024, will increase as the season continues but should never exceed 82). Can anyone tell me where all of those extra entries are coming from when I run this in PyCharm?

I have also tried using total_games = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//tbody/tr[@id and @data-row]') but I get the same result. I have also tried making it more specific with the following two lines but when those are used PyCharm returns a length of 0 for total_games. In both of those cases when inspecting the page manually, the correct results are returned.

```
total_games = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//table[@id="pgl_basic"]/tbody/tr[@id and @data-row]')
```

and

```
total_games = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//tbody/tr[contains(@id, "pgl_basic") and @data-row]')
```

Comment: Have you printed all of the 113 elements and identified the the ones you did not expect to find?  Perhaps you might find some explanation.

Comment: I get 113 lines of this:
<selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="36842018-3a18-4b48-bfd1-93dae8d61bd3", element="55f2c67f-1b6a-4903-b301-30ed52323aeb")>

With the random numbers and letters being different for each line.

Comment: Yeah, that's the (unfortunate) default output format when you print an element.  Try printing just the element's attributes.

Comment: Can you tell me which attribute I can get? Those are entire rows, so if I try .text it fails.

I have also tried to change the xpath to total_games = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//tbody/tr[@id and @data-row]/th[@data-stat="ranker"]') so that it gives the number of each game, but when I do that the length of find_elements_by_xpath becomes 0.

Comment: Assuming the ids are all unique, it should be enough to just print the id of each element.  Try `element.get_attribute("id")`

Comment: I'll try to explain it the best I can without you knowing the contents of the site. I'm getting per_game, playoffs_per_game, totals, playoffs_totals, per_minute, playoffs_per_minute, etc and each of those has a number of instances for every year the player played in the league (ex. per_game.2018, per_game.2019, etc) But none of those are the actual contents of the table I'm inspecting, those are all different tables themselves on a different page.

Comment: Okay, so it seems the xpath `//tbody/tr[@id and @data-row]` is not specific enough -- it matches extra elements that you don't want.  You need a more specific xpath that matches ONLY the elements you actually want.

Comment: I'm confused as to how those elements are being found when the program is run on PyCharm but when searching for that exact same xpath on the page itself, I'm not seeing any of those entries and am instead getting the correct elements?

Comment: What does "when searching for that exact same xpath on the page itself" mean?  How are you performing this search?  What tool are you using?

Comment: And again, it would probably be quite helpful to identify one of the actual elements that is in the unwanted excess, to see exactly where it is on the page.

Comment: Well that's the thing, when printing the id of each individual element, 100% of them are incorrect. It's not like I'm getting the contents of that table plus extra elements, I'm only getting contents which do not exist on that table. But when inspecting in the browser using the exact same xpath, it gives me the correct elements.

Comment: _when printing the id of each individual element, 100% of them are incorrect_ Can you give some examples?

Comment: So basically, if you go to the link I posted in the question, and you look at the 2023-24 Game Logs table, and then inspect and search for the XPath as I defined it, you will get 66 results, each of them is a row in the table. But in Pycharm if you have it go on that page and have the same XPath defined, and then print the id's, instead of 66 results you will get 113, and none of them are the rows of the table. They all seem to be the titles of tables on a completely different page, rather than the rows of that specific table as they should be.

Comment: Then it sounds like you've made some other basic mistake, like using the wrong url in `driver.get()`.  Please update the question to include a **complete** program we can run ourselves, instead of just small snippets.

Comment: So this was a weird one. The URL was correct, but for some reason even though you could see the script going to the correct page, when it came time to collect those elements, it was still taking them from the previous page. I added a WebDriverWait function to make it wait for a specific element on the page I needed before collecting the elements and now it works. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this was a weird one. The URL was correct, but for some reason even though you could see the script going to the correct page, when it came time to collect those elements, it was still taking them from the previous page. I added a WebDriverWait function to make it wait for a specific element on the page I needed before collecting the elements and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

It's because there are like 8 tables in the html. A far better way to do this is grab the stats tables, then get the max value in `'G'` column if you want the players number of games, or just the `'RK'` column or length of the table for total games.

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/j/jokicni01/gamelog/2024'
df = pd.read_html(url)[-1]
df = df[df['G'].ne('G')]

print(len(df))
```